# Firebase Storage PutFile Kotlin Crashing

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

My goal is to try upload a photo that I have selected from Photo Library or Camera captured, to Firebase Storage into a bucket/folder called ProfilePictures.

Everything works absolutely fine at first, I have used Picasso to assign the image to ImageView and Intent for Camera, except for when I call `uploadPhoto()`. The application crashes and relaunches on `fileReference.putFile(imageUri)...`.

Here is my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="true" />
```

I am using Firebase Storage version, which is in my build.gradle file -> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'

Here is my code:

```
    private var mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilePictures")
```

```
private fun uploadFile(name: String, callback: ()->Unit) {
        if (selectedProfileImage != null) {
            val imageUri = selectedProfileImage ?: return
            var fileReference = mStorageRef.child(name + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri))
            println(fileReference)
            fileReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener {
                    println("Profile Image upload Successful")
                    callback()
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    println("Profile image upload failed")
                    println(it.stackTrace)
                    println(it.localizedMessage)
                    callback()
                }

        } else {
            println("No profile picture selected")
            callback()
        }
    }
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
2019-12-03 14:23:34.521 7580-7761/com.fisherassociates.mt18academy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseStorage-Upload-1
    Process: com.fisherassociates.mt18academy, PID: 7580
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.fisherassociates.mt18academy-CsL1s9aKJKR7OHyF2sQSHw==/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.getCurrentAuthToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:148)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:65)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:57)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:457)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:257)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:198)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:1106)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Add you logcat stack trace so that we can identify the actual problem

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo the stack trace is not in the question - I had logcat set to 'Show only selected application' so was clearing when crashed.

Comment: Make the app crash again and provide it.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo, I've fixed the problem now as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. I used Firebase tool in Android Studio to setup Storage which in turn added the implementation in my build.gradle app file to version 16.0.4.

After finding -> [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-settokenprovider/56100196)

I then looked at the Firebase Android release notes:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

By changing the version to 19.1.0 the code now works.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'