# Upgrading minsdk version to 16 crashing the android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase databasereference and it is available in database upgraded version 19.2.0 and so i have to upgrade my minsdk version to 16 to make it compatible.

Making this change is crashing the app as soon as it it opened. I am not sure what has gone wrong. I am attaching the terminal error message and call stack when the app crashes

```
    Process: com.app.virtualbloodbank, PID: 26262
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider(Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.app.virtualbloodbank-J10_hidcZXu_pvvSPh7GEg==/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:70)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:55)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:159)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:561)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:303)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:267)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:252)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.2.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
    [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-settokenprovider)

Comment: awesome, this works. thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-settokenprovider